# Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two dropdownlist and a button. I used the breakpoint in my project and everything is working fine. But as soon I am getting out of the function of the button this is the error I am getting:

> Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.

Here is my code to that button:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ddlPlayer1.SelectedItem.Value != "0" || ddlPlayer2.SelectedItem.Value != "0" && ddlPlayer1.SelectedItem.Value != ddlPlayer2.SelectedItem.Value)
        {
            lblPlayer1Score.Text = Repository.Instance.ReturnScore(ddlPlayer1.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlPlayer2.SelectedValue.ToString()).Rows[0][0].ToString();
            lblPlayer2Score.Text = Repository.Instance.ReturnScore(ddlPlayer2.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlPlayer1.SelectedValue.ToString()).Rows[0][0].ToString();


        }

        ddlPlayer1.DataBind();
        ddlPlayer2.DataBind();
    }
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: In addition to the posted answers here, I found another possible cause for this error.  See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9236671/412107) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1603506/412107).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Make sure you are not databinding multiple ddls to the same datasource.
Being selected is an attribute of an item, therefore, if different ddls
select different items from the same datasource, each of the ddls ends up
with multiple items selected which is probably what is happening here..

Comment: This also occurs in an unbound DropDownList if you add the same ListItem to more than one ddl.

Comment: Thanks @Laramie, that's exactly what I did.  I created a "Please select" list item and added it to each drop down.  That seems to confuse the site.  Re-creating it for each drop down did the trick

Comment: Thanks @Laramie, you fixed my issue as well! I had my 'please select..' list item in a 'util' library, now I use it as an accessor with only the 'get' defined, using 'new' inside for each request.

Answer (score 119):

Usually this error occurs when you load your ddl as following:

```
ddl.FindByValue("parameter").Selected = true;
```

To overcome this error, you should clear the previous selection of your ddl as following:

```
ddl.ClearSelection();
ddl.FindByValue("parameter").Selected = true;
```

Or you can do as following:

```
ddl.SelectedItem = "parameter";
```

I hope i could help someone. ;-)

Comment: ClearSelection() was what I needed!

Comment: You can't use: ddl.SelectedItem = "parameter"; because SelectedItem is read only (to be more precise it's a property and the framework expose just the get accessor)

Comment: Solved my problem too, thanks. Too bad the framework doesn't tell you which ddl did the exception... could be problematic if you have lots of them on the screen.

Answer (score 22):

This code will solve this issue:

```
YourDropDownId.ClearSelection();
```

Comment: The best answer

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to add two other list items to to top of the `DropDownList`'s list after reading data into the `DropDownList`.

One of the item was "please pick one...", and the second one was "Not listed here...".
So I have created a list item:

```
ListItem li1 = new ListItem("please pick one...", "999");
ListItem li2 = new ListItem("not listed here...", "555");
```

Then I have tried to add these two `ListItems` to the three `DropDownList`. After that I have encountered the same error.

After creating new ListItem instances for each `DropDownList`, the problem has gone away...

Answer (score 1):

A previous answer mentions `ddl.SelectedItem = "parameter";` as an option. However, `SelectedItem` is readonly.

Using `ddl.SelectedValue = "value"` will also resolve the OP's error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ddlPlayer1.SelectedIndex>0 || ddlPlayer2.SelectedIndex>0)
        {
            lblPlayer1Score.Text = Repository.Instance.ReturnScore(ddlPlayer1.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlPlayer2.SelectedValue.ToString()).Rows[0][0].ToString();
            lblPlayer2Score.Text = Repository.Instance.ReturnScore(ddlPlayer2.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlPlayer1.SelectedValue.ToString()).Rows[0][0].ToString();


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to get the error:

```
        ddlFromBudget.Items.Clear();

        ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
        newItem.Text = "Not Set";
        newItem.Value = "0";
        ddlFromBudget.Items.Add(newItem);

        if (ddlB1.SelectedValue.ToString() != "0")
        {
            newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = ddlB1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            newItem.Value = "1";
            ddlFromBudget.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
```

The line `ddlFromBudget.Items.Add(newItem);` sets `newItem.Selected = True`.
Without the line `newItem = new ListItem();`, you get the error because the selected flag is now true on both items added to the ddl.

Answer (score -1):

**If you are checking that both dropdownlist selected index should be higher than 0. Then you should check it like 
if (ddlPlayer1.SelectedIndex>0 || ddlPlayer2.SelectedIndex>0)
{}

I think the error comes to use "DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value".