# How to set a dropdownlist item as selected in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set selecteditem for asp. net dropdownlist control programmatically.

So I want to pass a value to the dropdownlist control to set the selected item where is the value of the item equal to the passed value.

Comment: And what's the problem/question?

Comment: show some code @farouk, then we will try to help you....

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
dropdownlist.ClearSelection(); //making sure the previous selection has been cleared
dropdownlist.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

Comment: But the problem with this is that you have to wrap it around an error check like Try() or a ListItem test. If the "value" has a value that does not exist in the dropdownlist, you will get an exception (object not found error I think).

Comment: Kinda necroing the thread but this does not work for me. Any new solutions maybe?

Comment: @gadria. it seems like you are missing the value in the dropdown you are trying to find through `FindByValue`

Comment: @RabNawaz I'm sure the `value` property I've given is there because when I send the value to my SQL query I see that the values are correct.

Comment: in my case this is not firing the "SelectedIndexChanged" event

Comment: @MartinMeeser I think, you are missing to set `AutoPostback = true`

Comment: @gadria, I necroing it again, it could be due to DataBing() (on ddl or page, whatever) being called again after you set selected value.

Answer (score 33):

You can set the `SelectedValue` to the value you want to select. If you already have selected item then you should clear the selection otherwise you would get "[Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138287/cannot-have-multiple-items-selected-in-a-dropdownlist)" error.

```
dropdownlist.ClearSelection();
dropdownlist.SelectedValue = value;
```

You can also use [ListItemCollection.FindByText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ListItemCollection.FindByValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
dropdownlist.ClearSelection();  
dropdownlist.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

> Use the FindByValue method to search the collection for a ListItem
>   with a Value property that contains value specified by the value
>   parameter. This method performs a case-sensitive and
>   culture-insensitive comparison. This method does not do partial
>   searches or wildcard searches. If an item is not found in the
>   collection using this criteria, null is returned, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you expect that you may be looking for text/value that wont be present in `DropDownList` ListItem collection then you must check if you get the `ListItem` object or `null` from `FindByText` or `FindByValue` before you access Selected property. If you try to access Selected when null is returned then you will get [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx).

```
ListItem listItem = dropdownlist.Items.FindByValue(value);

if(listItem != null) 
{
   dropdownlist.ClearSelection();
   listItem.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Mentionned solution didn't work for me but this one like a charm

Comment: @eka808 Could to elaborate on your comment per Yosi's question?

Answer (score 26):

You can use the FindByValue method to search the DropDownList for an Item with a Value matching the parameter.

```
dropdownlist.ClearSelection();
dropdownlist.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

Alternatively you can use the FindByText method to search the DropDownList for an Item with Text matching the parameter.

Before using the FindByValue method, don't forget to reset the DropDownList so that no items are selected by using the ClearSelection() method. It clears out the list selection and sets the Selected property of all items to false. Otherwise you will get the following exception.

```
"Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very nice and clean example:(check this great tutorial for a full explanation [link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx))

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems(
              this IEnumerable<Album> albums, int selectedId)
{
    return 
        albums.OrderBy(album => album.Name)
              .Select(album => 
                  new SelectListItem
                  {
                    Selected = (album.ID == selectedId),
                    Text = album.Name,
                    Value = album.ID.ToString()
                   });
}
```

In this MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470380.aspx) you can read de `DropDownList` method documentation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
dropdownlist.ClearSelection(); 
dropdownlist.SelectedValue = value;
```

This will work when **value** will be dropdown value, mostly people trying to set with dropdown text.

Answer (score -4):

Set dropdown property

```
selected="true"
```