# Jquery to reset dropdownlist's selected index is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a check box and a dropdownlist on my mvc4 razor page

when I uncheck my check box ,i need to reset my dropdownlist's selection to 0

```
$("#chkProcess").click(function (event) {
        //on-click code goes in here.
        var chkProcess = $(this);
        if (chkProcess.is(':checked')) {
           //do process
        } else {
            $('#locationSelectList').val('0');
            alert("" + $("#locationSelectList option:selected").val());

        }
    });
```

When I uncheck my checkbox ,I am getting the alert showing selected Index=0,but on the screen its not actually reflecting the change.
But I need the dropdown to reset the selection on the screen also .Why I am seeing this behaviour and what am I doing wrong here?

I have these Jquery files referenced on my _layout page

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.treeview.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried all these

```
$('#locationSelectList').attr('selectedIndex', '0');
 $('#locationSelectList').val('0');
```

but I can see in alert message its resetting the selected index,but not getting same reflected on the page.

Comment: Does this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974992/how-to-set-a-dropdownlist-item-as-selected-in-asp-net) help?

Comment: Try this link http://www.9nit.com/jquery/set-the-selected-index-of-a-dropdown-using-jquery-35201.html

Comment: can u try  alert("" + $("#locationSelectList").find("option:selected").val());

Answer (score 4):

check out this link.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheeban/wGAMW/2/

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkProcess"/>
<select id="locationSelectList">
    <option value="chennai">chennai</option>
    <option value="bangalore">bangalore</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
$("#chkProcess").click(function (event) {
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) { 
        $('#locationSelectList').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    } 
 });
});
```

Comment: let me know if this works for you ? if not are you getting any error in console ? if you were using chrome press ctrl+shift+j the debug mode will enable

Answer (score 1):

Select the first option(Default selected option)?

Try this :

```
document.getElementById("<%#mydropdownlist.ClientID%>").value = 0;
```

Another Method using `Jquery`

```
$check .click(function() {

    $ddlHeader.find('option:first').prop('selected', 'selected');

});
```

I have a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/9YM4P/71/)** for you

Comment: For more visibility you can add jquery code samples in answer itself along with fiddle, as question is tagged for jquery.

Comment: It's not working for me . I am using Jquery 1.5.1 don't know how to make this working with Jquery 1.5.1

Comment: @Millar is there a specific reason why you are not using the latest jQuery?

Comment: @Millar try  `$('#target').val([0]);` for default first selection

Answer (score 0):

Use the .[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function:

```
$("#chk").on("click", function()
{
    if($(this).prop("checked"))
    {
        $('#locationSelectList').val('0');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/BDh6X/1/

Comment: What exactly isn't working? As you can see in the jsFiddle, it works, so something else might be messing up your javascript. I have it when it gets checked, just change it to when it's unchecked.

Comment: with my code itself ,I can see the alert showing the selected index resetted.But this change is not reflected on the UI --means on the page its not showing as resetted

Comment: That means that you might not be selecting the select box correctly. Right click your element and try to obtain the real id, with the Developers Tools. That might be your problem.