# Dropdownlist losing values on button submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page.

THE DROPDOWN'S SELECTED VALUE IS LOST.

When i click search, i can perform a server side event and return to the page with everything working fine. When i press update, sadly, my combo boxes lose their values.  I have enbabledViewState to true for master page, and current page and even on all of the controls. Any ideas how i could begin to approach this? The values are gone by the time we reach page_load event. There are no other life cycle events.

```
Page_Load()
{
  if(!PostBack)
  {
    //Populate a dropdown.
    This is where the dropdown is safely populated.
  }
}

btnClickSearch()
{
}

btnClickUpdate()
{
}
```

The two buttons on the page.

NOT WORKING

```
<asp:Button id="btnUpdate" class="fg-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" runat="server" Text="Update" onclick="btnClick_Update" onclientclick="return updateNotes();" style="width:auto;"/>
```

WORKING

```
<asp:Button id="A2" runat="server" onclick="btnClick_Submit" OnClientClick="return searchNotes();"  class="fg-button ui-state-default  ui-corner-all" style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; width:auto;" Text="Search"></asp:Button>
```

The onclient click event for both buttons calls blockUI and returns true. Any idea why these would be different in behaviour?

Also, none of the dropdown items have duplicate values.

Comment: Do you mean after you pressed the update, the drop down selected value return to default which is the first one but not the one you selected previously?

Comment: Submit button works fine. When i press update, the selected values of my combo boxes are lost. The application does not know what was selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two controls.

Button1 and button2.  Button 1 works fine. Button 2 does call it's server side event, but when this occurs we get a CKEditor dissasembly.

I have a jquery UI dialog containing the CKEditor and an asp button.  When this button it clicked all of the values are lost on the server side and the disassembly is shown.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/custom/dialog-patch.js"></script>

 <span style="width: 500px; height: 100%">
            <CKEditor:CkEditorControl id="CKEditor1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
            </CKEditor:CkEditorControl>
 </span>
```

Definition

```
$(function() {
            // to load editor
            CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {

                // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event
                // data.
                var dialogName = ev.data.name;
                var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

                // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
                // interested on (the "Link" dialog).
                if (dialogName == 'link') {
                    // remove contents
                    dialogDefinition.removeContents('target');
                    dialogDefinition.removeContents('upload');
                    dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');
                    // Get a reference to the "Link Info" tab.
                    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');

                    // Remove the "Link Type" combo and the "Browser
                    // Server" button from the "info" tab.
                    infoTab.remove('linkType');
                    infoTab.remove('browse');
                }
                else if (dialogName == 'table') {
                    // Get a reference to the default tab.
                    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
                    infoTab.remove('selHeaders');
                    infoTab.remove('txtHeight');
                    infoTab.remove('txtCellSpace');
                    infoTab.remove('txtCellPad');
                    infoTab.remove('txtCaption');
                    infoTab.remove('txtSummary');
                    infoTab.remove('cmbAlign');
                }
            });
        });
```

Function to open the dialog containing the CKEditor.

```
 function EditDialog(element,supplier,codeId,name, category,categoryCode, noteId,templateText) {
            var numberOfNotes = $(element).parent().children('.text').length;
            var noteBody = "";
            if (numberOfNotes == 1) {
                noteBody = $(element).parent().children('.text').html();
            }
            if (noteBody == "") {
                noteBody = templateText;
            }
            $('#<%=esupplier.ClientID %>').val(supplier);
            $('#<%=ename.ClientID %>').val(name);
            $('#<%=enotecategory.ClientID %>').val(category);
            $('#<%=hfCategoryCode.ClientID %>').val(categoryCode);
            $('#<%=hfNoteID.ClientID %>').val(noteId);
            $('#<%=hfIdCode.ClientID %>').val(codeId);
            var dialogeditcontainer = $('#editdialog').dialog('open');
            dialogeditcontainer.parent().appendTo(jQuery('form:first'));
            CKEDITOR.instances[$('#editorName').val()].setData(noteBody);
            return false;
        }
```

Definition

```
$(function() {
            // to load editor
            CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {

                // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event
                // data.
                var dialogName = ev.data.name;
                var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

                // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
                // interested on (the "Link" dialog).
                if (dialogName == 'link') {
                    // remove contents
                    dialogDefinition.removeContents('target');
                    dialogDefinition.removeContents('upload');
                    dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');
                    // Get a reference to the "Link Info" tab.
                    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');

                    // Remove the "Link Type" combo and the "Browser
                    // Server" button from the "info" tab.
                    infoTab.remove('linkType');
                    infoTab.remove('browse');
                }
                else if (dialogName == 'table') {
                    // Get a reference to the default tab.
                    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
                    infoTab.remove('selHeaders');
                    infoTab.remove('txtHeight');
                    infoTab.remove('txtCellSpace');
                    infoTab.remove('txtCellPad');
                    infoTab.remove('txtCaption');
                    infoTab.remove('txtSummary');
                    infoTab.remove('cmbAlign');
                }
            });
        });
```

Finally the two aspx buttons. The first one works, the second one does not. The second button is located in a dialog with the ckeditor.

THIS ONE WORKS.

```
<asp:Button id="A2" runat="server" onclick="btnClick_Submit" OnClientClick="return searchNotes();"  class="fg-button ui-state-default  ui-corner-all" style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; width:auto;" Text="Search"></asp:Button>
```

THIS ONE DOES NOT

```
<asp:Button id="btnUpdate"  runat="server" onclick="btnClick_Update" onclientclick="return updateNotes();" style="width:auto;" Text="Update" class="fg-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" />
```

Both of the onclientclick events call BlockUI return true.

[image: Disassembly]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to set a session for selected one after pressing update button:

```
btnClickUpdate()
{
  Session["DDLValue"] = dropdownlist.SelectedValue;
}
```

On page load, get the session and set it to drop down list if it is not NULL:

```
if(Session["DDLValue"] != null)
{
  dropdownlist.SelectedValue = Session["DDLValue"].ToString();
}
```

Following links would help: [Set selected value for drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974992/how-to-set-a-dropdownlist-item-as-selected-in-asp-net)

Comment: I want to keep the selected value.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by hit the page load before the button click event? Do you mean you getting error message because the session is null?

Comment: @user2723463 It sounds like something else is causing a postback, therefore triggering the Page_Load event again. Set your dropdowns AutoPostBack property to false. dropdowns can cause postbacks by default.

Answer (score -1):

Try populating if it is a postback as well..

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack || Page.IsPostBack)
{
//Populate a dropdown.
This is where the dropdown is safely populated.
}
```

Reference... [Page.IsPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Why don't you just remove the condition? No need for an `if` check when it always returns true.

Comment: How will this help me retain the dropdown values that were selected by the user? This will repopulate and reset ALL of the controls.

Comment: @codeman061988 It is the selected value that is lost, not the contents.

Comment: On your `btnClick_Update` event, you could assign the selected value of the dropdown list to a Session variable. `Session["MySession"] = dropdown.SelectedValue;` Then if the page is a postback, declare the selected value from your session. `dropdown.SelectedValue = Session["MySession"].ToString();`

Comment: There are a number of dropdowns and does not represent a robust pattern for moving forward. I would like to know what i've done wrong with this control.