# Using Javascript to set a Asp:Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, zurb-foundation

I've tried various ways to set the dropdownlist to no avail.  In developer tools I can see the `selectedIndex` change appropriately and I can see the option node changed from selected `false` to selected `true`.  But when the popup modal opens, the dropdownlist displays the 1st option which is blank.  If I close and reopen the popup it will display whatever I manually selected.  How can i programmatically set the dropdownlist value?

Mark Up

```
   <%--Address Popup--%>
    <div id="location_modal" class="reveal-modal modal_location" data-reveal>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Locations(Update/New)</legend>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
           <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server">Location:*</asp:Label>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddLocationNames" runat="server" class="input_ddllocationName"></asp:DropDownList>
       </div>
```

Js

```
    locationNameId = 'MainContent_lvAddresses_lblAddressLocation_' + g_index
    locationName = document.getElementById(locationNameId).innerHTML;

    var select = document.getElementById("MainContent_ddLocationNames");

    for (var i = 0; i <select.options.length; i++){
        if(select.options[i].innerHTML == locationName){
            //select.selectedIndex = i;
            //$(".input_ddllocationName").selectedIndex = i;
            select[i].selected = true;
            }
            else{
            select[i].selected = false;
            }
        }
```

Droplist 
    id: MainContent_ddLocationNames

```
1. selected="selected" value="" 
2. value="1">TESTING            
3. value="2">TESTING AGAIN      
4. value="3">MY FAVORITE LOCATION 
5. value="4">MGM GRAND BALLROOM A
```

Comment: selected tells you whether or not the user selected the item or not, but doesn't tell you what he selected.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974992/how-to-set-a-dropdownlist-item-as-selected-in-asp-net).  You don't need JS for that.

Comment: the js is used to populate all fields on the popup modal (several others are retrieved thru an ajax call)

Comment: The default behavior is shown in the link I provided, since you are using ASP.NET.  Otherwise you'll need an answer like Moby's or user14178135's below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the foundation, the dropdownlist has some 'special' markup.

In the Js I had to add some extra lines of code.  Thank You Google Dev Tools!

```
//Find out which row should be selected
var indexSave = 0;
for (var i = 0; i<select.options.length; i++){
    if(select.options[i].innerHTML == locationName){
        indexSave = i;
        break;
        }
    }

   //Set the current node to the Location Name
   $('#MainContent_ddlLocationName').next().children().first().text(locationName);

   //Remove all selections
    $('.input_ddlLocationName ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });

    //Select the Location Name based on index
    var selectLi = indexSave + 1;
    $('.input_ddlLocationName ul li:nth-child(' + selectLi + ')').addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery on the page:

```
$(".input_ddllocationName").val(locationName);
```

Or locationNameId, depending on which is the value attribute for the options.

Comment: I even tried hardcoding the location name and it still didn't show when the popup opened.  $(".input_ddllocationName").val("TESTING");
//$(".input_ddllocationName").val(locationName);

Comment: Val() will look for the value attribute of the option. So .val("1") in your case would be the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using core JavaScript, then this should work.

```
locationName = document.getElementById(locationNameId).innerHTML;

var select = document.getElementByClassName("input_ddllocationName")[0];

for (var i = 0; i <select.options.length; i++){
    if(select.options[i].innerHTML == locationName){
        select.selectedIndex = i;
        // OR select.value = select.options[i].value;
    }
    else{
        select[i].selected = false;
    }
}
```