# Can not select multiple item in dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 dropdownlist on my page. Items of dropdownlist gets selected from database table. Problem is when I try to get 2 different dropdownlist selected value from same table (Column is different) It shows me this

> Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM freeGiftOffers WHERE ID = @ID";
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio2").ConnectionString;
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString)) {
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query)) {
        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter()) {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) {
                sda.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
                    string selectedProductList1 = dt.Rows(0)("productID").ToString;
                    drpProductsList.Items.FindByValue(selectedProductList1).Selected = true;
                    string selectedProductList2 = dt.Rows(0)("freeProductID").ToString;
                    drpProductsList2.Items.FindByValue(selectedProductList2).Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see you are accessing the same row index twice `dt.Rows(0)("productID")` and `dt.Rows(0)("freeProductID")`. You can check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138287/cannot-have-multiple-items-selected-in-a-dropdownlist

Comment: But column is different

Comment: Have you turned on "multiselect" in the properties window or by code?

Comment: @KristófTóth No. I didn't done anything like that And I don't think such things can be done

Comment: Could you post the code that generate items of 2 dropdown list? I guess that 2 dropdowns are used the same items.

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting/clearing the selected item before you select another.

```
var selectedProductList1 = dt.Rows(0)("productID").ToString();    
drpProductsList.ClearSelection();
drpProductsList.SelectedValue = selectedProductList1;
```

Comment: This is not working. Both DropDownList selects first item from list not which comes from database

Comment: So you have a default item that doesn't come from the DB and that item is selected at the time you attempt to select another?

Answer (score 0):

There is't a built in way to do this with a dropdownlist in ASP. You could do it with a ListBox control. Refer below link.

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3828/web-forms-working-with-aspnet-server-controls/6/